# How do I display one item of a list at a time that changes per reload?

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress site and I'd like to modify it so that on each page there is a small section at the bottom that displays one item from a list, and that item can change on a reload or when selecting a new page.

This site basically does that near the bottom(Stuff we like): http://www.respawn.com/

I have only a vague clue as to how I could accomplish this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you clarify what you mean by "one item from a list"?

If this is a list of posts, you could add a WP Query to the bottom of your theme that pulls in one random post.  You could organize your "things" as posts into a specific category and have the query show posts from only that category.

If your needs are more simple, I would imagine there's a suitable plugin, like this: http://wordpress.org/plugins/randomtext/

Comment: this should be posted as comment not answer.